# determine the shear stress and bending moment of the next axis

Tags: homework-and-exercises, elasticity, continuum-mechanics, stress-strain

[image]

I have problems to raise the equations. They could recommend me a text to be able to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the bearing can be modelled (as it should) as hinges, then you have

[image: Mom_Shear_1]

The procedure goes as follows.

a) Take out the bearings (hinges) and replace them with their vertical reactions (no moments):
 the system is statically determined, so apply equilibrium of forces and moments to get the reactions.

b) Take a cross-section cut at $x$; replace with the internal force $T(x)$ and moment $M(x)$;
in this case we have no axial tension $N(x)$;
 use signs as appropriate with the reference system adopted, which shall always be indicated.

[image: Mom_Shear_2]

c) Consider (as conventionally done) the left part ($0$ to $x$); add the external forces and reactions and equilibrate like before.

Comment: Excuse me you could explain a little more; For example, first point I have to verify the static conditioning ie the sum of forces in the axes must be zero and also, the conditioning of the moment, then, I determine the reactions, right? And then, as I do the diagrams, can you explain me a little more?

Comment: @SantiagoSeeker: I expanded my answer a little more, wish it is sufficient.